# Selecting data-id CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

I'm in the middle of writing a functional test with CasperJS and I need to click a button, which is straightforward enough. The issue I'm having is that I'm not using an "li" list, rather the elements are in a "div list".

My HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="List">
  <div class="list-item>
    <div class="list-item-detail" data-id="1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item>
    <div class="list-item-detail" data-id="2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see, the only difference between the two items in the list is their data-id. My question, then, is how can I casper.click() the first element. I know how to access a class or id, but I'm not sure how to access data-id="1". Any insights?

EDIT: Using Fanch's answer below, I'm pretty sure I was able to click on the appropriate item, but after much hair-pulling as to why things still weren't working, I realized that my page only responds to touch events, so while I can click on the item, nothing actually happens. Looks like this might be hairier than I had thought.

Comment: The easiest would be to generate touchevents in the page context. There is a possibility that this might not work as phantom support is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
casper.click('.list-item-detail[data-id="1"]');
```

You could also do it like that I think:

```
casper.click('.List > .list-item:first-of-type > .list-item-detail');
```

Answer (score -1):

Fanch's selector seems to be OK for me, very well answered, however you could also accomplish like this:

```
casper.click('.list-item-detail:first');
```

Comment: `:first` is not a valid CSS pseudo-element. This is jQuery syntax and not applicable to casperjs.